# Convert date format to mm-dd-yyyy with returning string as string and convert dates only in an array?

Tags: javascript

I have a date function to convert date to mm-dd-yyyy and its working fine, when my array containing `['2019-08-11','2019-01-21','2019-11-11']` dates like this.But, in  my case array containing `['one','2019-08-01']`.when this occurs how to return my result as,  `['one','01-08-2018']` like this.How can i achieve this                           in JavaScript.

```
function formatDate(date) {
    console.log(date);
    console.log('coming');
    var d = new Date(date),
    month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
    day = '' + d.getDate(),
    year = d.getFullYear();
    if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
        if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;
        return [month, day, year].join('-');
}
```

Comment: whats the logic behind year `['one','2019-08-01']` `['one','01-08-2018']` or it just typing mistake?

Comment: @omi  that's typing mistake.there is no logic. my response array containing['one','2019-08-01'].In this how to return my string and formatted date using the above dat function

Comment: To see the provided Fiddle, please hit F12 to see the console.

Answer (score 0):

You can transform `yyyy-mm-dd` into `dd-mm-yyyy` like so:

```js
 

var str = "2019-08-01";
var formatted = str.split("-").reverse.join("-");

console.log(formatted);
```

Comment: Although the date provided in the question is ambiguous, I think OP wanted mm-dd-yyyy not dd-mm-yyyy

Answer (score 0):

You should use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to format date. To check for valid date used `isValid()` moment function.

```js
var dateArr = ['one', '2019-08-01'];
console.log(getDate(dateArr));

function getDate(arr) {

  for (var key in arr) {
    var tempDate = moment(new Date(arr[key]));
    if (tempDate.isValid()) {
      arr[key] = tempDate.format('DD-MM-YYYY');
    }
  }

  return arr;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please do not add a comment on your question or on an answer to say "Thank you". Comments are meant for requesting clarification, leaving constructive criticism, or adding relevant but minor additional information – not for socializing. If you want to say "thank you," vote on or accept that person's answer, or simply pay it forward by providing a great answer to someone else's question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution:

```
var dates =['one', '2019-03-1', 'try', '2016-01-31','2018-11-11'];
  dates.forEach(function(entry) {
    //formatDate(entry);
    console.log("Got: " + formatDate(entry));
  });   
;
function formatDate(d) {
    console.log(`Processing '${d}'`);
    date = new Date(d);
    if (isNaN(date)) {
        console.log(`'${date}' is not a date.`);
        return d;
    } else {    
        console.log(console.log(`'${date}' is a date.`));
        return d.split("-").reverse().join("-");
    }
}
```

Her is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Meziano/par849d1/)

Comment: @Hari: Let us know it you still have a problem.

Comment: I got the output.

Comment: This is exactly what you want, right? If so please accept my answer.

Comment: You seem not to be satisfied with my answer although it does what you want. Dommage!